# What algorithm for feedback control to maintain heart rate

Tags: algorithms

I am writing an application that will maintain heart rate within a specified range by adjusting the resistance on a turbo trainer.

I could cobble together something that would gradually increase resistance until heart rate reached the right level but I imagine reaching the desired heart rate quickly, not overshooting and maintaining it might not be a trivial exercise.

Sadly I did not study computer science but I imagine that this problem has been solved many times before and I was hoping for a relatively simple algorithm that I can implement without spending a long time fine tuning and improving it.

Comment: (Reads [*control loop theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) (and implementation) rather than computer science.)

Comment: Control theory is traditionally a part of electrical or mechanical engineering. You can try your luck in [electronics.se].

Comment: Thanks, have re-posted